# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ReactJS APP

Tags: reactjs

This is the App component, Error in taskList const how can I find what is undefined

```
function App(props) {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.tasks);
  const taskList = tasks.map(task => (
    <Todo
        id={task.id}
        name={task.name}
        completed={task.completed}
        key={task.id}
      />));
  function addTask(name) {
    const newTask = { id: "todo-" + nanoid(), name: name, completed: false };
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  }
```

Comment: This because map is a inbuilt js function for arrays. but here taskList is undefined so it can't access map function. what you can do is check if taskList is not undefined and then continue your task.

if(taskList){
const taskList = tasks.map(task => ( //Do your thing here)
}

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks array seems to be undefined since that is what map is called on. Probably when initially mounting the component the array is still undefined and only set later. You could write:

```
    const taskList = tasks ? tasks.map(…) : [];
```